# Sign in page: Using a combination of first person and second person

Tags: login, content, grammar

I've noticed on many sign in pages that it's quite common to use a combinaton of first person and second person, for example Facebook uses 'Keep me logged in' which is first person, as well as 'Forgot your password' which is second person.

Is there a reason they haven't used one case for both pieces of content?

Answer (score 2):

In general, these words are used to make a connection with the user; to engage the user a little bit more (try these sentences without *me* or *your* and you'll feel the distance).

With that in mind, you could see the whole interaction as a dialogue with someone else, in which you, really, are the *boss*.

In general, the first person is used to tell the application what to do, in your example, it tells the application to remember you and keep you logged in.
As for the action that *you* can perform, the second person is used, like a friendly butler telling you the actions he can do for you. In this example, you can take the action the recover your password.

In that respect, it seems a bit strange to see 'my pictures', again from the dialogue perspective, you don't want to see the butlers pictures - labeled 'my pictures' - but YOUR pictures. It really depends on the perspective, are you talking *against* something or someone, or is everyhing from the point of the user. If *me* or *your* is not absolutely necesarry, don't use them at all.

I'd say that - as a rule of thumb - *once you've started the dialogue form, you stay in the dialogue form*.

Sources:

- http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/the-grammar-of-interactivity/
- http://www.designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns/Your_vs._My

Comment: I believe it is "my pictures"  because you're actually giving the command "view my pictures", they have just cut out the verb as it made the phrase too lengthy.

Comment: That is probably the verb and the reason why they didn't include it - I've edited my potential answer to reflect on this, as it is IMO totally up to the front-end dev to decide to go with "dialogue" or "user POV", there are no rights or wrongs - but once you go with one way or another, better stick to it :-) ... or the old famous rule of: consistency!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely agree with avoiding me/you.

In my experience, when people try to use these modifiers (e.g., "My Documents") it almost always introduces inconsistency. If it's "My Documents," Isn't it also "My Settings," "My Account," My Contacts," and so forth? And if everything is "Mine," why is it necessary to continually restate that? Is the user a two-year-old?

As for the voice, the two examples shown could be simply "Forgot password" and "Stay logged in." The most common need for a voice is in instructions and error messages, which should always be second person, e.g.: "Please enter your password." This almost always requires for the sake of consistency that no other part of the application use first person. Otherwise this error message would have to be "I must enter my password," which is awkward and Gollum-like.

Comment: Came across these guidelines in the Yahoo Style Guide: https://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/social/core/yourvmy.html